# If an average of 10 students are late to class on any given day

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If an average of 10 students are late to class on any given day (assume all students are equally likely to be late to class), what is the probability that in a class of 30 students exactly 10 students are late
?
Given solution is 15.3% for 10 students.  2.46% for half the class . Any ideals/ guide that we can approach this   question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn this into a Bernoulli trial problem. The probability that a single student is absent is $\dfrac{10}{30} = \dfrac{1}{3}$. The probability that exactly ten are absent would be:

$$\dbinom{30}{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{10}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{20} \approx 15.3\%$$

Exactly 15 students:

$$\dbinom{30}{15}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{15}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{15} \approx 2.47\%$$

Exactly $k$ students are absent:

$$\dbinom{30}{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^k\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{30-k}$$